# Error in eclipse while importing project from TFS

Tags: eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin

I am facing some problem while importing project in eclipse. Import is happening if I try it from different machine. I am getting the below error when I try to import from my machine,

An internal error occurred during: "Reconciling local TFS workspace".
java.lang.NullPointerException

I feel there is some issue with the local repository. I cleared 'AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation' folder, still the same issue. How to deal with this issue ?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Answer (score 0):

As importing projects from TFS on a different machine works, your TFS is running in good status.

Based on the error message, the issue seems relates to your workspace. Please use [Team Explorer Everywhere](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47727) command line to delete the broken workspace:

```
tf workspace /owner"xxx" /collection:"XXX"

tf workspace /delete /collection:"XXX" "workspace name"
```